# How do I custom set the origin when use the mapping node?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, texture-coordinates

[image]

I'm going to use the mapping node to rotate my X-mark texture.

However, the origin isn't centered on the X-mark.
How do I custom set the origin when I use mapping nodes?

---

**Test Chris's Answer**
The origin of the geometry seems like independent of the rotation origin of the mapping node.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is add a vector math node before mapping node, set it to add. Now you can easily change the origin by changing the value of vector math node

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i could not fix it with the vector math node alone. I also had to add $-0.5$ to the mapping node.

[image: image showing node setup]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/161937)

Answer (score -1):

1. Tap on cross to select
2. object -> set origin -> to geometry

[image]

Comment: I tested the geometry origin, but it didn't work. I added a test gif to the question.